# Add Outside Class

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am using RestSharp. I am trying to create this JSON:

```
            //request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"properties\":{\"name\":\"{0}\",\"hs_product_id\":\"{1}\",\"hs_recurring_billing_period\":\"24\",\"recurringbillingfrequency\":\"monthly\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"price\":\"{2}\"}}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

How do I create a wrapper called properties about my LineItemHubSpotModel class? Here is my code:

```
        private LineItemHubSpotModel AddLineItems(string name, long productId, decimal price)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/line_items?hapikey=" + apiKey);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");

        request.AddJsonBody(Serialize(GetLineItemHubSpotModel(name, productId, price)));
        //request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"properties\":{\"name\":\"{0}\",\"hs_product_id\":\"{1}\",\"hs_recurring_billing_period\":\"24\",\"recurringbillingfrequency\":\"monthly\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"price\":\"{2}\"}}".Replace("{0}", name).Replace("{1}", productId).Replace("{2}", price), ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();

        return deserial.Deserialize<LineItemHubSpotModel>(response);
    }

    private object Serialize<T>(T item)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
    }

    private LineItemHubSpotModel GetLineItemHubSpotModel(string name, long productId, decimal price)
    {
        LineItemHubSpotModel model = new LineItemHubSpotModel()
        {
            Name = name,
            HsProductId = productId,
            Price = price,
            Quantity = 1,
        };

        return model;
    }
```

Comment: The question is rather confusing, but do you just mean `new { properties = YourThingHere }`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to wrap your object, you can do it with a class that has that property, or just use an anonymous type, for example:

```
var myObject = GetLineItemHubSpotModel(name, productId, price);
var itemToSerialise = new { properties = myObject};
request.AddJsonBody(Serialize(itemToSerialise));
```